# css cannot be view on the ipad when an element have a width bigger that 920px

Tags: html, css, ipad, ios-simulator

I have develop a website with dimensions base on monitors.
When I saw it on an Ipad the rigth corner is missing the css colors.
Take a look

[image]
Here is the HTML code.

```
 <div id="nav-top">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
            <ul class="menu-nav-top">
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Top Social Links -->
            <ul class="social-links">
                <li>contact</li>
                <li>Twitter</li>
                <li>Facebook</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--#wrapper-->
    </div><!--#nav-top-->

    #nav-top {
        background: url("img/bg_body_blue6.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
        height: 36px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 4;
    }

    .wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 1146px;
    }
```

After looking at the source code, I found that since the width of the wrapper is bigger than the safe zone of the ipad (920px),
the ipad only applay the css to the viewable area and the rest wich you need to scroll to see dosn't have the style.

Is there a way I can fix this (get the css on the non viewable area or the area you need to scroll to see)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem was that the your site was the wrong size you wouldn't be able to see the stuff being rendered on the right side at all.

What are you doing w/ the ULs? is one float left and the other float right? If that is the case then most likely it's because you're setting the width on the "wrapper" and not on the "nav-top".

if you change it to something like

```
#nav-top {
  background: ...;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1146px;
}


.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1146px;
}
```

it should work okay. Also clearing the floats on the UL's should fix this problem as well.  So adding this to your already existing code

```
 .wrapper:after {
   content: ' ';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 0px;
   visibility: hidden;
   clear: both;
 }
```

you should be fine as well.

I agree with Andy though, you shouldn't use fixed widths (unless they are design dependent) because it never translates well when going mobile.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Brodie. I just make the above modifications

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to build this based on percentages rather than absolutes if you want it to also display nicely on the iPad.

For your particle situation, you could add a `max-width:100%;` to the wrapper to force it to either be 1146px wide or when the screen/browser is less than that, it will just be the entire width instead.

So change the .wrapper CSS to:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1146px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Another solution is to give the width percentages only instead of absolute pixels. But the above should be fine for what you're trying to accomplish... (just make sure nothing else in the div needs the full 1146px e.g. `img {max-width:100%}` might also help)

But that potentially only answers the current problem on hand. Ideally if you want your website to fit all browser sizes, devices and shapes you want to build it [**responsive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). A good framework for developing responsive sites is http://foundation.zurb.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to look into the [Viewport Meta Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). It is used to set the scale of the website you're viewing proportional to the screen size.

It can be included in the  of your html file like so:

```
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```